How do I find a transistor and diode equivalent to the ones in the photos below?
I'm looking for the two transistors in the photos below, but I can only find the partial numbering on sites like aliexpress.



The symbol on the second component photo suggests to me that it is two diodes in one package.

so this second one should I look for a double diode?

I don't have much choice as I haven't found these components for sale here in Brazil as I live in the countryside.
EDIT: I've edited the post title to fit the topic

Digikey should ship to Brazil

please add the part numbers to your post ... some people cannot vies images

All major vendors, Digikey, Mouser, RS, Farnell and others ship all over the world, including the Brazilian countryside.

An equivalent transistor is for example MJE13005 and an equivalent diode is for example STPS2045CT.

The first part is a Jilin Sino Microelectronics 400V BJT
The second is a dual Schottky diode from the same maker.
lcsc has equivalents in stock for the first part and an equivalent for the second, for about 45/25 cents each, plus about $13 for (slow 7-15 business days) shipping to Brazil or $47 for FedEx 3-7 business days.
Digikey is another option, but shipping will be more like $40-$65.
